# How to determine the number of transparent pixels in an animated GIF frame?

Tags: python, image-processing, imagemagick, gif, animated-gif

I am aware that transparent pixels in an animated GIF frame are determined by a transparent color index, where we can set a pixel to be transparent by assigning it to the value of the transparent color index when the transparent color flag is set to 1.

However, I have no clue how to determine what is the transparent color index of an animated GIF frame and whether the transparent color flag is set, as well as how to determine which pixels in a frame are of this color. I have looked around tools such as [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/), [wand](https://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.6.5/wand.html), and [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), but I am not able to formulate a solution to find the number of transparent pixels.

Some pseudocode (in Python style) I have in mind to formulate my solution:

```
def count_transparent(frame):
    count = 0
    if transparent_flag(frame):
        transparent_pixel = find_transparent_pixel(frame)
        for row in frame:
            for col in frame:
                # Compare the colors
                if frame[row][col] == transparent_pixel:
                    count += 1
    return count
```

#### Question

What tools/methods can I use (and how can I use them) to obtain information to find information pertaining to the transparent color flag and the transparent pixel for each animated GIF frame, where I am also allowed to iterate over each position of a frame?

The closest I have found is [gifsicle](https://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/), which appears to allow me to find information about the transparent color flag and the transparent pixel, but I am unable to iterate over each position of a frame with it. I appreciate something that I can use with Python, though a solution of any language is also welcome.

Comment: PIL `Image`s have an [`info`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html?highlight=info#PIL.Image.Image.info) dictionary with various pieces of information depending on the format. After looking a the [source code](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/PIL/GifImagePlugin.html?highlight=GIF) for handling GIF files, it looks like one of the keys in this dictionary is `info["transparency"]` — so it looks like the info you need may be available.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do please? Do you have a sample GIF wherein you know the number of transparent pixels you seek? If so, please share it? Are you taking about animated GIFs or just normal, single-frame images?

Comment: Are you aware that frames of an animated GIF do not necessarily cover the entire image area? A frame sometimes only applies to and updates a smaller area than the entire canvas so do you consider pixels outside the update area to be transparent because they cannot be seen?

Comment: @martineau Cool, I'll take a look at the `info` dictionary and see what I can get from that.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Any GIF works (I don't have a sample where I know the number of transparent pixels). I'm specifically singling out GIFs because I'm trying to study how often the technique you pointed out is applied, where we perform updates to a smaller area of a frame to optimize for space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ImageMagick, you can determine the number of transparent pixels by extracting the alpha channel, negate it so transparent is white and then getting the average (in range 0 to 1) of that image multiplied by width*height. For the 10th frame (starting at 0)

```
convert image.gif[9] -alpha extract -negate -format "%[fx:mean*w*h]" info:
```

should give you the number of transparent pixels.

Comment: Awesome, this does exactly what I need. As a follow-up question, is it possible to determine which index in the color palette of a GIF frame (be it local or global) to be the one that defines the transparency pixel?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know that answer. identify -verbose reports a transparent color. But I am not sure if that is what you are looking for?

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, though I probably need to find a way to just report that transparent color alone. Thanks for the help!